# How to save the choosen file in the app directory?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP, right now what my function is doing is that, user can choose txt file type message running loop, after that file will convert into csv and will start downloading on user machine, what i want to do is that, a copy of that file will also save it my app directory, i don't know how to do that.

**My function**

```
protected function insertData($data) {
    $lang = $this->load->language('transaction/export_csv');


    $files = $this->request->files;

    $file = $this->request->files['file'];
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $extension = strtolower($ext);

    $errorCode = $file['error'];

    if($extension != 'txt'){
        $json = array(
            'success' => false,
            'error' => $lang['error_file']
        );
    } else {
        $handle = fopen($file['tmp_name'], "r");
        $new_file = "CSV-".date('d-M-y H:i:s').".csv";
        copy($file['tmp_name'], 'upload/CSVFILE.csv'); //UPDATED LINE

        header('Content-type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$new_file.'"');

        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
        $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        $f2 = fopen('upload/CSVFILE.csv', 'w'); //UPDATED LINE

        if ($handle !== FALSE) {
            $row_no =0;
            while (($rows = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                foreach($rows as $phone_no) {
                    fputcsv($f, array($phone_no, html_entity_decode($data['message'])."\r\n\r\n".$row_no));
                    fputcsv($f2, array($phone_no, html_entity_decode($data['message'])."\r\n\r\n".$row_no)); //UPDATED LINE

                    $row_no++;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        fclose($f);
        fclose($f2); //UPDATED LINE
    }
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Write the data to the actual file first, instead of into the output stream. Use `readfile` to read the content from that file and output it to the client afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

```
copy($file['tmp_name'], 'PATH TO THE APP DIRECTORY');
```

Make sure the php process has the write permission to the app directory.

**To choose a file name**

Suppose the app directory is *~/app*, you want the file name to be *myfile.csv*, then use

```
copy($file['tmp_name'], '~/app/myfile.csv');
```

**To save as a csv file**

Create a new file:

```
$f2 = fopen('~/app/myfile.csv', 'w');
```

Then you put the output to both files:

```
$data = array($phone_no, html_entity_decode($data['message'])."\r\n\r\n".$row_no);
fputcsv($f, $data);
fputcsv($f2, $data);
```

Comment: ANSWER UPDATED: i choose text file, it save a file in my app directory which i uploaded with the name 'DIR_UPLOAD', also i think it overwrite the file when i upload another file it doesn't create another file until and unless i delete it, furthermore i want to save the converted file e.g 'CSV' cause complete data is in csv file. @shingo

Comment: Brother i updated my answer your code is working but when i upload another file, it overwrite the previous file.... maybe because of the same name. @shingo

Comment: Of course, this is an example, you need use different names

Comment: i put the '$file_name', the name which i gave the downloadable file, but not working.

Comment: But what you give is `$new_file` I see in the post.

Comment: yeah that my typo in comment, should i do like this: `copy($file['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.'$new_file');` ??? @shingo

Comment: Yes just like this.

Comment: Look Bro, `copy($file['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$new_file);`    `$f2 = fopen('upload/'.$new_file, 'w');` .... i did exactly like this but after that no file save in my upload dir. @shingo

Comment: First, these 2 methods are conflicted, you may choose one to keep. Second is if you exactly use `upload/` as the output directory I think it usually not work, the path is relative to the script file, you need use an absolute and existed path.